# Como obter o Paramentro em um Web service em C# enviado do Android

Tags: java, c#, android, web-service, visual-studio

Estou consumindo um Web service desenvolvido em C#, a partir de uma aplicação em Android. Ao enviar tipos simples por parâmetro como string, int ou long, consigo obter a informação normalmente apenas colocando o mesmo tipo no parâmetro da declaração do método Web service. Mas não sei como obter um objeto complexo criado em java dentro do método web service em C#.
O objeto enviado tem o mesmo nome em ambas aplicações, mas não são exatamente iguais devido nomes das propriedades.

obs:
-Estou usando o Ksoap2 no android, e a classe esta sendo serializada e enviada para para o web service sem erros.
-talvez poderia obter o objeto como XML, mas que tipo eu colocaria no paramento?

Chamada web service

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        PropertyInfo object = new PropertyInfo();
        object.setName("obj");
        object.setValue(ordemServicoBO);
        object.setType(ordemServicoBO.getClass());

        request.addProperty(object);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "ordemServicoBO",new OrdemServicoBO().getClass());
        envelope.implicitTypes = true;
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
        androidHttpTransport.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");

        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);//Aqui a chamada é feita normalmente sem erro, e entra no método do web service

        SoapObject responseNoXML = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
```

Classe em Java

```
public class OrdemServicoBO implements KvmSerializable {

private long idOrdemServico;
private long IdOrdemServicoCategoria;
private long idOrdemServicoLocal;
private long idHotel;
private long idUsuarioExecutante;
private long idUsuarioSolicitante;
private long idArea;
private String dataAbertura;
private String descricao;
private String status;
private AreaBO areaBO;
private UsuarioBO usuarioSolicitante;
private UsuarioBO usuarioExecutante;
private OrdemServicoCategoriaBO ordemServicoCategoriaBO;

public void setOrdemServicoCategoriaBO(OrdemServicoCategoriaBO ordemServicoCategoriaBO) {
    this.ordemServicoCategoriaBO = ordemServicoCategoriaBO;
}

public OrdemServicoCategoriaBO getOrdemServicoCategoriaBO() {
    return ordemServicoCategoriaBO;
}

public void setUsuarioExecutante(UsuarioBO usuarioExecutante) {
    this.usuarioExecutante = usuarioExecutante;
}

public void setUsuarioSolicitante(UsuarioBO usuarioSolicitante) {
    this.usuarioSolicitante = usuarioSolicitante;
}

public UsuarioBO getUsuarioExecutante() {
    return usuarioExecutante;
}

public UsuarioBO getUsuarioSolicitante() {
    return usuarioSolicitante;
}

public void setDataAbertura(String dataAbertura) {
    this.dataAbertura = dataAbertura;
}

public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
    this.descricao = descricao;
}

public void setIdArea(long idArea) {
    this.idArea = idArea;
}

public void setIdHotel(long idHotel) {
    this.idHotel = idHotel;
}

public void setIdOrdemServico(long idOrdemServico) {
    this.idOrdemServico = idOrdemServico;
}

public void setIdOrdemServicoCategoria(long idOrdemServicoCategoria) {
    IdOrdemServicoCategoria = idOrdemServicoCategoria;
}

public void setIdOrdemServicoLocal(long idOrdemServicoLocal) {
    this.idOrdemServicoLocal = idOrdemServicoLocal;
}

public void setIdUsuarioExecutante(long idUsuarioExecutante) {
    this.idUsuarioExecutante = idUsuarioExecutante;
}

public void setIdUsuarioSolicitante(long idUsuarioSolicitante) {
    this.idUsuarioSolicitante = idUsuarioSolicitante;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getDataAbertura() {
    return dataAbertura;
}

public long getIdArea() {
    return idArea;
}

public long getIdHotel() {
    return idHotel;
}

public long getIdOrdemServico() {
    return idOrdemServico;
}

public long getIdOrdemServicoCategoria() {
    return IdOrdemServicoCategoria;
}

public long getIdOrdemServicoLocal() {
    return idOrdemServicoLocal;
}

public long getIdUsuarioExecutante() {
    return idUsuarioExecutante;
}

public long getIdUsuarioSolicitante() {
    return idUsuarioSolicitante;
}

public String getDescricao() {
    return descricao;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setAreaBO(AreaBO areaBO) {
    this.areaBO = areaBO;
}

public AreaBO getAreaBO() {
    return areaBO;
}

@Override
public Object getProperty(int arg0)
{
    switch(arg0)
    {
        case 0:
            return getDataAbertura();
        case 1:
            return getDescricao();
        case 2:
            return getStatus();
        case 3:
            return getIdOrdemServicoCategoria();
        case 4:
            return getIdOrdemServico();
        case 5:
            return getIdOrdemServicoLocal();
        case 6:
            return getIdArea();
        case 7:
            return getIdHotel();
        case 8:
            return getIdUsuarioExecutante();
        case 9:
            return getIdUsuarioSolicitante();

    }
    return null;
}
@Override
public void setProperty(int arg0, Object arg1)
{
    switch(arg0)
    {
        case 0:
            setDataAbertura(arg1.toString());
            break;
        case 1:
            setDescricao(arg1.toString());
            break;
        case 2:
            setStatus(arg1.toString());
            break;
        case 3:
            setIdOrdemServicoCategoria(Long.parseLong(arg1.toString()));
            break;
        case 4:
            setIdOrdemServico(Long.parseLong(arg1.toString()));
            break;
        case 5:
            setIdOrdemServicoLocal(Long.parseLong(arg1.toString()));
            break;
        case 6:
            setIdArea(Long.parseLong(arg1.toString()));
            break;
        case 7:
            setIdHotel(Long.parseLong(arg1.toString()));
            break;
        case 8:
            setIdUsuarioExecutante(Long.parseLong(arg1.toString()));
            break;
        case 9:
            setIdUsuarioSolicitante(Long.parseLong(arg1.toString()));
            break;
    }

}
@Override
public void getPropertyInfo(int arg0, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo arg2)
{
    switch(arg0)
    {
        case 0:
            arg2.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            arg2.name = "CategoryId";
            break;
        case 1:
            arg2.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            arg2.name = "Description";
            break;
        case 2:
            arg2.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            arg2.name = "Name";
            break;
        case 3:
            arg2.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
            arg2.name = "CategoryId";
            break;
        case 4:
            arg2.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
            arg2.name = "CategoryId";
            break;
        case 5:
            arg2.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
            arg2.name = "CategoryId";
            break;
        case 6:
            arg2.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
            arg2.name = "CategoryId";
            break;
        case 7:
            arg2.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
            arg2.name = "CategoryId";
            break;
        case 8:
            arg2.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
            arg2.name = "CategoryId";
            break;
        case 9:
            arg2.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
            arg2.name = "CategoryId";
            break;

        default:break;
    }

}
@Override
public int getPropertyCount()
{
    return 10;
}
}
```

Método Web service C#

```
[WebMethod]
public OrdemServicoBO Exportar(OrdemServicoBO ordemServicoBO)//quando é executado o androidHttpTransport.call() é chamado esse método, mas o retorno, que é o mesno recebido por parâmetro, esta vazio.
{
    return ordemServicoBO; //Atualmente retorna vazio
}
```

classe em C#

```
public class OrdemServicoBOAPP
{
    private long _idOrdemServico;

    public long IdOrdemServico
    {
        get { return _idOrdemServico; }
        set { _idOrdemServico = value; }
    }
    private long _IdOrdemServicoCategoria;

    public long IdOrdemServicoCategoria
    {
        get { return _IdOrdemServicoCategoria; }
        set { _IdOrdemServicoCategoria = value; }
    }
    private long _idOrdemServicoLocal;

    public long IdOrdemServicoLocal
    {
        get { return _idOrdemServicoLocal; }
        set { _idOrdemServicoLocal = value; }
    }
    private long _idHotel;

    public long IdHotel
    {
        get { return _idHotel; }
        set { _idHotel = value; }
    }
    private long _idUsuarioExecutante;

    public long IdUsuarioExecutante
    {
        get { return _idUsuarioExecutante; }
        set { _idUsuarioExecutante = value; }
    }
    private long _idUsuarioSolicitante;

    public long IdUsuarioSolicitante
    {
        get { return _idUsuarioSolicitante; }
        set { _idUsuarioSolicitante = value; }
    }
    private long _idArea;

    public long IdArea
    {
        get { return _idArea; }
        set { _idArea = value; }
    }
    private String _dataAbertura;

    public String DataAbertura
    {
        get { return _dataAbertura; }
        set { _dataAbertura = value; }
    }
    private string _descricao;

    public string Descricao
    {
        get { return _descricao; }
        set { _descricao = value; }
    }
    private string _status;

    public string Status
    {
        get { return _status; }
        set { _status = value; }
    }
    private AreaBOAPP _areaBO;

    public AreaBOAPP AreaBO
    {
        get { return _areaBO; }
        set { _areaBO = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fernando, por favor poste o código relevante. Existem vários bibliotecas para Android capazes de fazer *unmarshalling* do XML em um objeto. Minha recomendação seria o [Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: acredito que se você enviar o objeto com o nome das propriedades iguais o próprio c# irá mapear esse objeto.

Comment: Coloquei o mesmo nome nas propriedades e nada mudou. Se eu pudesse obter o XML como string daria pra montar o objeto manualmente, mas já mudei para string e tbm vem vazio.

Comment: Se o webservice é seu e está em WCF aconselho anotar os métodos e criar endpoints para trabalhar com Rest. Sua vida será bem mais fácil. De qualquer modo, talvez o Aerogear sirva para você: http://aerogear.org/

Answer (score 2):

Pelo seu código parece que você já aprendeu a implementar a interface `KvmSerializable` para mapear objetos complexos para XML e vice-versa. Caso contrário, veja esse exemplo do [Wsdl2Code](http://www.wsdl2code.com/pages/Example.aspx) (que, por sinal, é uma ferramenta excelente para gerar esse tipo de *boilerplate code* para você). Uma vez que você esteja com o mapeamento dos objetos complexos pronto, a chamada é razoavelmente simples:

Você já adicionou um mapeamento de um um nome para uma classe. Nesse caso não sei se `ordemServicoBO` é um nome de um elemento na chamada ou na resposta do seu serviço. No caso do serviço `Exportar` você precisa mapear as duas para o mesmo tipo de objeto (`OrdemServicoBO`):

```
// Estou assumindo algumas coisas sobre o WSDL e o serviço Exportar
// O nome "ordemServicoBO" podem ser completamente diferente
// Em alguns casos pode ser que o request ou a resposta estejam encapsuladas, em
// outro objeto, etc
envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "ordemServicoBO", new OrdemServicoBO().getClass());
```

Feito isso, vamos adicionar as propriedades do *request* (conforme mapeamento acima que prevê um parâmetro `ordemServicoBO`)

```
// Veja que novamente o nome desa propriedade depende do seu WSDL
request.addProperty("ordemServicoBO", ordemServicoBO);
```

Ao fazer a chamada, assumindo que os mapeamentos estejam corretos, seu serviço do lado do .NET irá receber um objeto completo:

```
 androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

Mais uma vez assumindo que o seu WSDL retorna um tipo complexo de resposta diretamente no corpo da resposta, para recuperar o valor do lado do Android basta fazer um *cast* desse objeto:

```
 OrdemServicoBO result = (OrdemServicoBO) envelope.getResponse();
```

Caso exista algum tipo de indireção você precisará tratar isso manualmente (novamente vide [exemplo do Wsdl2Code](http://www.wsdl2code.com/pages/Example.aspx))

**Obtendo os XMLs gerados para efeito de *debugging*:**

```
androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

androidHttpTransport.requestDump; // string contendo a chamada
androidHttpTransport.responseDump // string contendo a resposta
```

## TL;DR

- Você já está mapeando tipos complexos através da interface `KvmSerializable`
- Agora é questão de acertar os mapeamentos entre *namespaces*, nomes e classes conforme seu WSDL.
- Use as propriedades `requestDump` e `responseDump` para obter Strings contendo XML

**Dicas:**

- Use um cliente externo como o [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) para testar chamadas e respostas. Ajuste o `OrdemServicoBO` até que a variável `requestDump` fique idêntica ao XML de *request* do SoapUI.
- Verifique seu WSDL ([exemplo](http://www.wsdl2code.com/SampleService.asmx?wsdl)), todos os elementos e mapeamentos devem responder aos `names`nas tags `<s:element>`.
- A ferramenta [Wsdl2Code](http://www.wsdl2code.com/pages/home.aspx) pode gerar tudo isso para você.

---

**Fonte:** [ksoap2-android -  Coding Tips And Tricks](https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks)

Comment: Vou olhar o Wsdl2 e estuda-lo. Acredito que a serialização do esteja sendo feita corretamente, pois não aponta erros e o conteúdo do bodyout parece estar correto. A obtenção de de tipos complexos como retorno do WS tbm esta certo, pois já estou fazendo isso sem problemas. Mas minha duvida está na parte do envio de objetos complexos em que vc diz "Ao fazer a chamada, assumindo que os mapeamentos estejam corretos, seu serviço do lado do .NET irá receber um objeto completo", qual é o tipo do parâmetro que o lado .NET vai receber? uma string com o XML do objeto enviado? Algum tipo XML?

Comment: Olá Fernando. Acho que você está olhando isso da perspectiva errada. O .NET pode consumir um DTO como você está fazendo sem problemas. Com isso o .NET irá gerar um WSDL para esse e os demais métodos declarados. Tente apendar `?wsdl` ao seu serviço para ver o que o .NET gerou. Agora é sua responsabilidade fazer o cliente serializar o objeto do *request* exatamente como o .NET espera receber o objeto.

Comment: Como você está tentando gerar o *request* manualmente muito provavelmente está cometendo erros de serialização (dica: preste atenção no seu método `getPropertyInfo`) além de não estar usando os nomes de elementos esperados pelo .NET.

Comment: Então minha dica é, ou use o `wsdl2code` para gerar tudo bonitinho a partir do WSDL (realmente não tem muito o que aprender, basta exportar o WSDL, submeter no site e fazer download do *client* gerado) ou tente acertar esse tipo de detalhe na unha.

Comment: Para acertar esse tipo de detalhe na unha novamente te recomendo furar a abstração, utilizar um cliente externo com o [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) para testar o serviço manualmente e aprender a construir os *payloads* para o seu serviço (já que o problema está no *request*). Uma vez que você tenha entendido como o seu *web service* funciona, faça com que seu código no Android construa o exato mesmo tipo de *payload* modificando o código cliente (você pode obter o *XML* crú através do método *androidHttpTransport.requestDump*). Ficou mais claro?

Comment: O que é importante ficar claro aqui é: A nível de SOAP o que existem são *payloads* no corpo de um *envelop*. O trabalho todo aqui é fazer com que o seu código cliente faça *marshalling* do objeto enviado na maneira que o serviço espera receber no *request*, e, analogamente, *unmarshalling* corretamente daquilo que o serviço retorna (essa segunda parte você disse que já acertou).

Comment: Sim, eu estava olhando da perspectiva errada. Enviei o objeto como o WS esperava e com a ajuda do requestDump tornou muito mais fácil. Apesar do C# montar automaticamente o objeto, algo que não gosto muito. Mas de qualquer maneira funcionou e ajudou muito. Obrigado

Comment: Fico feliz em ajudar Fernando. Se o problema está resolvido não se esqueça de aceitar minha resposta ;).